# How to remove SvelteKit

Tags: javascript, sveltekit

I have some error with SvelteKit when I run  this code :"npm run dev -- --open". It has the issuse like this: Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module. I think maybe the error related to   SvelteKit v1.0.0-next.199 because I tried several solutions. I also add  "type": "module" in package.json, but it not work.My node version is 16.3.0. So anyone know how to remove SvelteKit?

```
"dependencies": {
    "chart.js": "^3.6.0",
    "cookie": "^0.4.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "svelte-i18n": "^3.3.13"
}
```

Comment: You are using ES6 modules and CommonJS modules at the same time. ECMAScript6 is different than CommonJS. Different module languages causes this error. Please ensure that all modules are capble of ES6 script or CommonJS script that you are using

Answer (score 0):

Remove moment library:

```
npm uninstall moment --save
```

As explained in the comment CommonJS libs and ECMAScript6 are different standards of JavaScript libs (packing) so you need to look for ECMAScript6 (ES6) libs

Use date-fsn instead moment for example, read more about it here https://date-fns.org/

Also Svelte is compiler when you install the libs install it as dev deps:

```
npm install date-fns --save-dev
```